# Retrieve post thumbnail as array

Tags: post-thumbnails, array

How can I retrieve the post thumbnail (featured image) as an array?
Using get_post_thumbnail() I noticed in the WP documentation that there is a third parameter from, which I understand, one would be able to set it to return the values as an array instead of a string, but I can't figure out how.
The reason I want to return the image as an array is to exclude unnecessary attributes in the output such as 'wp-post-image' etc.

Problem solved:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), $size);
```

Comment: Staffan, please, add the solution as an Answer and mark this topic as solved.

Comment: I have added the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src). As per the Codex:

```
$attachment_id = 8;
$size = 'full';

// returns an array
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
```

Although the return is said to be:

> ```
> [0] => url
> [1] => width
> [2] => height
> ```

There is a fourth element that indicates if it is the full image *(false)* or an intermediate image *(true)*:

```
[3] => is_intermediate
```